# Clutch Adjustment

Tags: clutch, suzuki

I have a 2004 Suzuki Wagon R. I only have to dip the clutch a fraction to   select a gear, which would indicate the clutch pedal is not coming off properly. The pedal is stiff, with no play in it. And I noticed recently it has started to slip momentarily when changing gear. Where the clutch cable is connected to the pedal there are two nuts. one for adjustment the other a locking nut.

To let the pedal off, and allow some free play, do I turn the adjustment nut clockwise or anti clockwise.

Comment: if the clutch is slipping it needs to be replaced You aren't going to remedy the situation by adjusting anything.

Comment: @agentp   I tend to disagree.  I had some 80's VW Rabbits that you could reach in, turn a plastic sprocket by hand, and add "clutch" as the material wore away.

Answer (score 1):

**tl dr:** Counterclockwise.

I haven't adjusted the clutch in your type of car before, but a rule of thumb I'd go with on this is, if you need to gain more free travel in the clutch pedal, you need to adjust the arm at the transmission (where the cable attaches) to have more travel. In your case, you should back the nuts off a little at a time until the release point is where you want it. Don't go too far down, though, because then you'll be in a situation where you won't be releasing the clutch all the way when you push the pedal down.